# Speedup processing of larger binary files

Tags: matlab, performance, file-io, bit-manipulation, binaryfiles

I have to process thousands of binary files (each of 16MB) by reading pairs of them and creating a bit-level data structure (usually a 1x134217728 array) in order to process them on bit level.

Currently I am doing this the following way:

```
conv = @(c) uint8(bitget(c,1:32));
measurement = NaN(1,(sizeOfMeasurements*8))   %(1,134217728)
fid = fopen(fileName, 'rb');
byteContent = fread(fid,'uint32');
fclose(fid);
bitRepresentation1 = arrayfun(conv, byteContent, 'UniformOutput', false);
measurement=[bitRepresentation1{:}];
```

Thus, I replaced `fopen` with `memmapfile` as below:

```
m = memmapfile(fileName,'Format',{'uint32', [4194304 1], 'byteContent'});
byteContent = m.data.byteContent;
byteContent = double(byteContent);
```

I printed timing information (using `tic`/`toc`) for the individual instructions and it turns out that the bottleneck is:

```
bitRepresentation1 = arrayfun(conv, byteContent, 'UniformOutput', false);  % see first line of code for conv
```

Are there more efficient ways of transforming `byteContent` into an array that stores a bit per index (i.e. that is a bit representation of `byteContent`)?

Comment: you are trying to read the individual bits into MATLAB?

Comment: Note that `fread(..., 'uint32')` will cast all `uint32` to `double`. And from these `double`s you then proceed to read the first 32 bits...You know that this changes the underlying data, right? A `double`  number has a wildly different representation in binary than the same number in  `uint32` does...

Comment: "_reading a single file takes minutes_" !!! A 16Mb file read in binary mode. No way. The time is consumed somewhere else ... or you have a serious problem with your hard drive ... backup everything quick before the thing burns in flames! ... unless ... are you trying to read the files from a network ?

Comment: @Hoki I tested it. It's not the reading that eats time; the `memmapfile()` is kinda useless. It's really only the `arrayfun()`.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis: Indeed, the most time-consuming part actually is (was) the arrayfun. Since this is replaced by your suggested code it is now the last code line (measurement=[bitRepresentation1{:}];).

Comment: As a general comment, you could have tracked down the bottleneck quicker using [`profile`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/profiling-for-improving-performance.html) instead of `tic` \ `toc`.

Comment: ... do you need it to be `uint8` or is that just to save space?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let looping over all numbers be handled by `bitget`. You loop over the bits:

```
fid = fopen(fileName, 'rb');
bitContent = fread(fid,'*ubit64');
fclose(fid);

conv = @(ii) uint8(bitget(bitContent, ii));
bitRepresentation = arrayfun(conv, 1:64, 'UniformOutput', false);

measurement = [bitRepresentation{:}]';
measurement = measurement(:).';
```

**EDIT** you can also try a direct loop:

```
fid = fopen(fileName, 'rb');
bitContent = fread(fid,'*ubit64');
fclose(fid);

sz = 64 * size(bitContent,1);    
measurement3 = zeros(1, sz, 'uint8');
weave = 1:64:sz;
for ii = 1:64
    measurement3(weave + ii - 1) = uint8(bitget(bitContent, ii)); end
```

but on my system, that is (surprisingly) slower than `arrayfun`...but, my MATLAB version is from the stone age, your mileage may be different. Give it a try

Comment: Thanks Rody, this brings the code line bitRepresentation = [...] down from 38seconds to 0.5 seconds! Now, the last line (measurements = reshape [...]) is the bottleneck with 5 seconds.

Comment: @user1192748 I don't think there's much you can do there to improve that...5.5 seconds over 38 is still quite the improvement.

Comment: @user1192748 ...well I've edited in a ***slight*** improvement (doesn't do much on my system, but something)

Answer (score 2):

Several things that seem to provide further improvement on Rody's suggestion:

1. (*minor:*) Using a local function instead of a function handle for `conv`.
2. (*major:*) Converting the result of `conv` to `logical` using `~~` instead of `uint8`.
3. (major:) `cell2mat` instead of `[bitRepresentation{:}]'`.

The result:

```
function q40863898(filename)

  fid = fopen(filename, 'rb');
  bitContent = fread(fid,'*ubit64');
  fclose(fid);

  bitRepresentation = arrayfun(@convert, 1:64, 'UniformOutput', false);    
  measurement = reshape(cell2mat(bitRepresentation).',[],1).';

  function out = convert(ii)
    out = ~~(bitget(bitContent, ii, 'uint64'));
  end

end
```

#### Benchmark result (on MATLAB R2016b, Win10 x64, 14MB file):

> ```
> Rody's vectorized method: 0.87783
> Rody's loop method: 2.37
> Dev-iL's method: 0.68387
> ```

#### Benchmark code:

```
function q40863898(filename)
  %% Common code:
  fid = fopen(filename, 'rb');
  bitContent = fread(fid,'*ubit64');
  fclose(fid);
  %% Verification:
  ref = Rody1();
  res = {Rody2(), uint8(Devil1())};  
  assert(isequal(ref,res{1}));
  assert(isequal(ref,res{2}));
  %% Benchmark: 
  disp(['Rody''s vectorized method: ' num2str(timeit(@Rody1))]);
  disp(['Rody''s loop method: ' num2str(timeit(@Rody2))]);
  disp(['Dev-iL''s method: ' num2str(timeit(@Devil1))]);
  %% Functions:
  function measurement = Rody1()
    conv = @(ii) uint8(bitget(bitContent, ii));
    bitRepresentation = arrayfun(conv, 1:64, 'UniformOutput', false);
    measurement = [bitRepresentation{:}]';
    measurement = measurement(:).';    
  end

  function measurement = Rody2()
    sz = 64 * size(bitContent,1);    
    measurement = zeros(1, sz, 'uint8');
    weave = 1:64:sz;
    for ii = 1:64
        measurement(weave + ii - 1) = uint8(bitget(bitContent, ii));
    end    
  end

  function measurement = Devil1()
    bitRepresentation = arrayfun(@convert, 1:64, 'UniformOutput', false);
    measurement = reshape(cell2mat(bitRepresentation).',[],1).';

    function out = convert(ii)
      out = ~~(bitget(bitContent, ii, 'uint64'));
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: +1, but I'm not sure how `cell2mat` will be faster, as internally it amounts to virtually the same thing...the bool thing is kinda really minor in my system, drowns in noise really...but you know, I still have the stone age MATLAB engine :)